# Call Second API If Condition is Met in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, axios

I need to call `http://sample-api-2.com` if `callAPI2` is true.
Also I need to pass the `response?.data.code` from `http://sample-api-1.com`.

What would be the correct way to do this?

```
export const createProduct =
  ({ data = null, callback = () => {}, callAPI2 = true }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
      });

      const [response] = await Promise.all([
        axios.post("http://sample-api-1.com", data),
        callAPI2 &&
          axios.post("http://sample-api-2.com", {
            productCode: response?.data.code,
          }),
      ]);

      const product = {
        productCode: response?.data?.code,
        productName: response?.data?.name || null,
      };

      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
        payload: product,
      });

      callback("success");
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.CREATE_PRODUCT_FAILURE,
      });

      callback("error");
    }
  };
```

Comment: What’s holding you back from just making another call?

Comment: @DanielA.White. I need to finish `http://sample-api-1.com` first so I can get `response?.data.code` to be pass onto the `http://sample-api-2.com`

Comment: Just break it out from the all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the response from the second API call (you don't show that you use it), you can refactor it this way:

```js
// ...
try {
  dispatch({
    type: constants.CREATE_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  });

  const response = await axios.post("http://sample-api-1.com", data);
  const productCode = response?.data?.code;
  if (!productCode) throw new Error('Product code not found');
  if (callAPI2) await axios.post("http://sample-api-2.com", {productCode});

  const product = {
    productCode,
    productName: response?.data?.name || null,
  };

  dispatch({
    type: constants.CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
    payload: product,
  });

  callback("success");
}
// ...
```

Comment: Will this wait for `callAPI2` to finish before calling this, right? ` dispatch({
    type: constants.CREATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
    payload: product,
  });`

Comment: @Joseph Yes, that’s what the `await` keyword does: suspend execution within the function scope until the promise settles.